# VS2022 extensions command initial checked state

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2022, vsixmanifest

I have a VS extensions command based on the default template. It has CommandFlag's `TextChanges` and `TogglePatternAvailable`. Depending on a config setting its initial state should be checked, however, this does not appear to be possible.

This is what I want to see on the first load:

[image: Checkbox]

I've tried setting `Checked` to `true` in the constructor of the command after creating the menu item:

```
menuItem1 = new OleMenuCommand(ExecuteCommand1, _, BeforeQueryStatus, new CommandID(CommandSet, Command1Id));
menuItem1.Checked = true; // This does not work
```

I've also tried using the `BeforeQueryStatus` to change the initial checked state, but it does not seem to be called when opening the Tools menu. Could this be a bug???:

```
private void BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run(async delegate
    {
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);
        menuItem1.Checked = true;
    });
}
```

Clicking the menu item once does trigger `BeforeQueryStatus` and the state is checked after that, proving that the code does work.

How can I set the initial checked state of the menu item to true depending on a config setting, so in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to get it to work by adding the `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute to my Package. It is unclear if this is the correct way to do this. The pacakge class now looks like this:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
[Guid(PackageGuidString)]
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
public sealed class MyPackage : AsyncPackage { ... }
```